# IndexError: list index out of range Showing when compiling script, but while running in powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a web scraper that scrapes Amazon, but ran into an issue with this error code **IndexError: list index out of range** I found that by pasting each line into a powershell window the program works as it should, but compiling the script I get the error.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search- 
alias%3Daps&field-keywords=graphics+card&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Agraphics+card'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"a-fixed-left-grid-inner"})
container = containers[0]
for container in containers:

    title_container = container.findAll("h2")
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    value_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"a-offscreen"})
    value = value_container[0].text
    print("Product: " + product_name)
    print("Price: " + value)
```

I'm trying to get the product name and product prices from Amazon.

Comment: There are three spots where an `IndexError` could occur, can you post the full error traceback? Basically, either `containers`, `title_container`, or `value_container` are empty. Also, it looks like your indentation is a little wonky in your `for` loop

Comment: Are you new to python? you don't compile python scripts.. Just a FYI

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code, I would just do the following:

Install/upgrade requests:

```
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

Your main problem was that `containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"a-fixed-left-grid-inner"})` was returning an empty list so everything else will fail as it relies on this list of 'containers'.
So we had to change things slightly...

And while I was there I made some more improvements; You need to use set a user-agent header or amazon will 503 your requests; requests library is so much easier to work with; it's usually better to use `attrs={}`

Here you go. But even setting a user agent is not foolproof, it is likely Amazon will spot your requests as being a bot/scraper in which case the code will tell you and exit:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search- alias%3Daps&field-keywords=graphics+card&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Agraphics+card'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
s = soup(r.text, 'html.parser')
# We can check for a "you're not a robot" in the page
if s.find('p', attrs={'class': 'a-last'}):
    print(s.find('p', attrs={'class': 'a-last'}).text)
    print('Amazon have spotted we are a scraper - oops!')
    sys.exit(1)

containers = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'a-fixed-left-grid-inner'})
for container in containers:
    product_name = container.find('h2').text
    value = container.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-offscreen'}).text
    print('Product: {}'.format(product_name))
    print('Price:'.format(value))
```

There re many ways/reasons for amazon assuming you to be a bot/scraper and you will hae get creative in ways to get around this.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm having an issue now when I try to run this nothing prints to the console. I did the pip3 install --upgrade requests and was told I already have the latest version.

Comment: Are any errors printed to console when you run this?

Answer (score 0):

problem is your price selector, because of there being different conditions, you may need conditional control in your codes:

```py
value_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"a-offscreen"})
```

as below:

#### 1 `class="a-offscreen"`

[image]

#### 2 `class="a-size-base a-color-base"`

[image]